# How to manipulate each element returned by $.AJAX in JQUERY

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this simple code snippet:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "http://localhost:3070/api",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data2) {
        ulEmployees.empty();
        $.each(data2, function(index, val) {
            $('#data').append('<tr><td>' + val.name + '</td></tr>');
            // $(this).addClass('donedone'); for adding class to each item
            // console.log($(this));
        });
    }
});
```

I would like to alert every single name returned by ajax. when I click on the `<tr>` in the table I should see the name popped up like `$('donedone').alert('val.name for example')`.

Comment: It depends on the type of the data returned by Ajax.If it's an Array , you could use `forEach` method like:`data.forEach(()=>{})`

Comment: Why don't you simply add that class directly to your tr i.e :`$('#data').append('<tr class="donedone"><td>' + val.name+'</td></tr>');`

Comment: the data returned is in json format like ```[[ { "name": "cc"}] ```  I added the class to the ```tr``` but I get it using ```$('#donedone').click('hi')```

Comment: the ```console.log()``` shows everything in the console, but I cannot alert  each name by clicking on it